# Portlets embedding on Social Office theme

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using liferay portal 6.1.1CE.

I wants to show the profile picture of the user on sidebar of the SO site home page(not public or private as they already include this feature).

For this, am going through many ideas,like put the image url in to the side bar div of portal-normal.vm file.but missing url error.

next one is ,using the profile portlet. i have include the portlet in the side bar by $theme.runtime("------PORTLET ID----");
But "This portlet has been undeployed. Please redeploy it or remove it from the page. "

is showing in the corresponding location of the side bar.

Help me?
Is it possible?
or any other way?

Comment: Although long time since asked, I have just come to this question. Just for the record and future reference, have you found a solution? If yes, what was the exception and how did you implement the requirement finally?